# SMACK API In Band registration fails with forbidden error

Tags: authentication, smack

I am using SMACK API's AccountManager class but failed to successfully create a new account. supportsAccountCreation() returns true.
The createAccount method fails with the following error.

```
D/SMACK: SENT (0): <iq to='xmpp.jp' id='e740L-48' type='set'><query     xmlns='jabber:iq:register'><username>MY_NEW_USER</username><password>**********************</password></query></iq>
D/SMACK: RECV (0): <iq from='xmpp.jp' id='e740L-48' type='error'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:register'><username>MY_NEW_USER</username><password>*****************</password></query><error code='403' type='auth'><forbidden xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/></error></iq>
W/System.err: org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$XMPPErrorException: XMPPError: forbidden - auth
W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketCollector.nextResultOrThrow(PacketCollector.java:232)
W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketCollector.nextResultOrThrow(PacketCollector.java:213)
W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.iqregister.AccountManager.createAccount(AccountManager.java:272)
W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.iqregister.AccountManager.createAccount(AccountManager.java:244)
..
D/SMACK: SENT (0): <auth xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl' mechanism='SCRAM-SHA-1'>*****************************************</auth>
D/SMACK: RECV (0): <failure xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><not-authorized/></failure>
```

**UPDATE: Code added here**
API v4.1.5

```
private void initialiseConnection() {
    Log.d("xmpp", "Initialising connection");
    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
    config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
    config.setServiceName(getServer());
    config.setHost(getServer());
    config.setPort(getPort());
    config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
    config.setSendPresence(true);


    XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementResumptionDefault(true);
    XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementDefault(true);
    connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config.build());

    connection.addConnectionListener(new XMPPConnectionStateHandler(this));
    connection.addConnectionListener(new XMPPAccountLoginHandler(this));
    connection.addConnectionListener(new XMPPOfflineMessageHandler(this));
    connection.addConnectionListener(new XMPPPingMessageHandler(this));
    connection.addConnectionListener(new XMPPReconnectionHandler(this));
    connection.addConnectionListener(new XMPPPresenceHandler(this));
    connection.addConnectionListener(new XMPPDeliveryReceiptHandler(this));
}

public void connect(final String caller) {
    if (ConnectionManagerHelper.hasDataConnection(context)){
        Log.d(TAG, "Data connection fine");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Data connection not avaiable");
    }
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> connectionThread = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        protected synchronized Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            if (connection.isConnected()) return false;
            isconnecting = true;
            Log.d("Connect() Function", caller + "=>connecting....");

            try {
                connection.connect();
                connected = true;
                notifyConnectionEstablishedEvent();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "(" + caller + ")" + " IOException: " + e.getMessage());
                notifyConnectionFailureEvent();
            } catch (final SmackException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "(" + caller + ")" + " SMACKException: " + e.getMessage());
                notifyConnectionFailureEvent();
            } catch (final XMPPException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "(" + caller + ")" + " XMPPException: " + e.getMessage());
                notifyConnectionFailureEvent();
            }
            return isconnecting = false;
        }
    };
    connectionThread.execute();
}

public void login() {
    try {
        connection.addAsyncStanzaListener(new StanzaListener() {
            @Override
            public void processPacket(Stanza packet) throws NotConnectedException {
                Log.d(TAG, packet.toXML().toString());
                notifyMessageStatusReceivedEvent(packet);
            }
        }, new StanzaFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(Stanza stanza) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        Log.d(TAG, "Attempting to login as " + loginUser);
        connection.login(loginUser, passwordUser);
        notifyConnectionConnectedEvent();
    } catch (SmackException.AlreadyLoggedInException e){
        Log.d(TAG, "Already logged on to chat server");
    } catch (XMPPException | SmackException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //if first login failed, try to create an account and then login
        Log.d(TAG, "Login failed. Trying to create a new account.");
        register();
    }
}

public void register(){
    Log.d(TAG, "Attempting to register");
    try {
        AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.getInstance(connection);
        if (accountManager.supportsAccountCreation()){
            Log.d(TAG, "Server supports remote registration");
            accountManager.sensitiveOperationOverInsecureConnection(true);
            Log.d(TAG, "Sending registration request");
            HashMap<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();
            attributes.put("email", "test@gmail.com");
            accountManager.createAccount(loginUser, passwordUser, attributes);
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "Server does not support remote registrations");
        }
    } catch (XMPPException | SmackException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have spent 3 days already googl-ing and stackoverflow-ing. 
Has someone seen and fixed this already?

Comment: Most likely issue is that you don't provide enough information when creating the account. Please show us the relevant code of yours.

Comment: @Flow, I have added the code block in the question. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Flow I have edited the question and added the relevant code. Is there anything else you need to understand.

Comment: @Flow, I spent some more time looking at the configuration after your comment and noticed the resource definition was missing. I added the resource and now I don't get forbidden error anymore. Instead I am getting bad-request now

Comment: @GorillaCoder i have also get this error while registration new user if you have any solution please provide that solution.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set access rules for registering new user. I have attached here the complete access rules. You can add this by clicking raw in access rules.

```
[{access,announce,[{allow,[{acl,admin}]}]},
 {access,c2s,[{deny,[{acl,blocked}]},{allow,[all]}]},
 {access,c2s_shaper,[{none,[{acl,admin}]},{normal,[all]}]},
 {access,configure,[{allow,[{acl,admin}]}]},
 {access,local,[{allow,[{acl,local}]}]},
 {access,max_user_offline_messages,[{5000,[{acl,admin}]},{100,[all]}]},
 {access,max_user_sessions,[{10,[all]}]},
 {access,mod_register,[{access_from,register_from},{access,register}]},
 {access,register,[{allow,[{acl,local}]}]},
 {access,muc_create,[{allow,[{acl,local}]}]},
 {access,pubsub_createnode,[{allow,[{acl,local}]}]},
 {access,register,[{allow,[all]}]},
 {access,register_from,[{allow,[all]}]},
 {access,s2s_shaper,[{fast,[all]}]},
 {access,trusted_network,[{allow,[{acl,loopback}]}]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code worked for me,

```
                AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.getInstance(connection);
                try {
                    if (accountManager.supportsAccountCreation()) {
                        accountManager.sensitiveOperationOverInsecureConnection(true);
                        accountManager.createAccount("name", "password");

                    }
                } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```